# Snapping/Shrinkwrap not working properly

Tags: modeling

I'm having quite the problem with the snapping tool, and before you ask, shrinkwrap modifier doesn't seem to change anything. I am trying to create the eyebrows for my character, so I want it to snap to the body mesh, and, well, it does snap to it, but inside the model. The normals of both the eyebrow and the rest of the model point outwards, so that's not the issue. Also, changing the orientation of the origin point doesn't seem to work either. I'm running out of ideas on to how to fix it. Any ideas? Here's a picture of the eyebrow outside and inside the model.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aO2K.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that, if vertices are perfectly snapped on a surface, the face they create will lie below a curved surface, and that's what's happening.

Even if the faces were perfectly lined up there would be a problem, called "Z fighting", where the renderer can't decide which material (face or eyeborws) to show, resulting in artifacts.

The best solution is to add a solidify modifier, so that some thickness resolve the problem and makes the eyebrows look better.

If you really want to stay flat, simply move by hand the eyebrows after projected on the curved surface.

[image]